# ESP8266 NtpClient parse int response into char* with 2 digits

Tags: c++, esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm writing time scheduler for switching sockets in specific time for microprocessor NodeMCU. I'm facing problem with parsing values. I fetched values (eg. '08:30') from database and saving to char*.
I'm fetching current time using NtpClient but it's int value.
My idea is to build char* from hour, ':' and minutes and compare with my value from DB but I have 2 problems:

- I need to create 2 digits char* from hour and minutes.
- I need to join these two strings

I don't have big experience in c++ and I can do it on my own but I want to do it in most efficient way because I'll run this script at least every 50 seconds.

Comment: don't do premature optimization, if you need to parse one `int` every 50 seconds, then trying to find the "most efficient" should be your last concern

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I can do it every second to make scheduled task execute on start of specific minute. But I don't think that it's good idea.

Comment: `I'm writing scheduler` .. `I fetched values (eg. '08:30') from database` Why do you need current time for a scheduler? Ooooch, it's a real life scheduler, not a [process scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)#Process_scheduler).

Comment: @KamilCuk correct. Sorry. I edited description

Comment: I would compare numbers not strings

Comment: Seriously, @largest_prime_is_463035818 is right. The time it will take to parse the numbers is nothing compared the time it will take to use NTP and access your database.You don't need to worry about doing it in the most efficient way. You're using the Arduino IDE. Have you tried using Google to search for "Arduino int to string"?

Answer (score 0):

I have minimal experience with C++. In addition, Arduino IDE is not full C++. My solution for this is:

```
int intLength( int N )
{
   if      ( N < 0  ) return 1 + intLength( -N );
   else if ( N < 10 ) return 1;
   else               return 1 + intLength( N / 10 );
}


void setSocketsState() {
      int currentHour = timeClient.getHours();
      int currentMinute = timeClient.getMinutes();
      char currentHourChar[10];
      char currentMinuteChar[10];
      itoa(currentHour, currentHourChar, 10);
      itoa(currentMinute, currentMinuteChar, 10);
    
      char dest[24] = "";
      if (intLength(currentHour) == 1) {
        strcat(dest, "0");
      }
      
      strcat(dest, currentHourChar);
      strcat(dest, ":");
      if (intLength(currentMinute) == 1) {
        strcat(dest, "0");
      }
      strcat(dest, currentMinuteChar);
    
      char* dateToCompare = dest;  // result: HH:MM
      socket1.handleCurrentTime(dateToCompare);
      socket2.handleCurrentTime(dateToCompare);
      socket3.handleCurrentTime(dateToCompare);
      socket4.handleCurrentTime(dateToCompare);
    }
```

There's still long way ahead of me. If you want to see this part of my project here's the link:
https://github.com/wojtaszek171/SmartHome/blob/master/esp8266/ESP1/ESP1.ino